# Get logcat from adb through wifi by java

Tags: java, android, adb

I want to get logcat from android device to PC through wifi by java. The program will get logcat by time and stop when a button is clicked.

So, I can connect to android through wifi and get logcat:

```
adb -s [ip_address]:5555 logcat -v time > D:\logcat.txt
```

This command runs well in cmd. It stops when I push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. But when I run this command in java code.

```
Process proc;
String command = "adb -s [ip_address]:5555 logcat -v time > D:\\Test_logcat.txt";
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        proc = rt.exec(command);
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                proc.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                proc.getErrorStream()));

        String line = null;
        while ((line = stdInput.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(line);

        while ((line = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It raises this error:

```
/system/bin/sh: can't create D:\Test_logcat.txt: Read-only file system
```

OK. I searched google and get the answer for this problem. [Here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120109/adb-locat-cannot-redirect-to-textfile-read-only-filesystem) , they explained:

```
In your command line example, you are running the ADB command from the Android terminal with / as current directory. So Android tries to write the output to /logcat.txt, which fails.
```

But, I don't understand why this command can run normally in cmd, but not in the java program. What is the trick here?

Moreover, do you nice guys can help me to fix this problem?

Comment: If you run this from command-line, you execute it on your PC. But If you run it from your program, you execute it on your Android device.

Go to your cur command line and execute `adb shell`. Now you are in your Android shell. From here you can execute the same commands as from your program.

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer. If I run a command "logcat -v time > /sdcard/logcat.txt", it seems good. But, I want to run it in the program, not in command line.

Comment: `> D:\\Test_logcat.txt` is interpreted by cmd in the first case, by the android shell in the second case, in which case it can't create this file. try reading the output and writing it to a file from java directly

Comment: use `logcat -v time -d > /sdcard/logcat.txt` in your program

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `logcat -v time -d > /mnt/local/log.txt`

Note: folder where you can store data is device dependent, do you may need to change the file path.